# How to make definition outside of enclosing namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, definition

I have a following code:

```cpp
namespace A
{

template <typename T>
void func(T);

namespace B
{
  class foo {};

  template <>
  void ::A::func(foo); // ERROR

  class bar {};

  class foobar {};
}

}
```

I have a `A::func<T>` template function and want to make specialization for `A::B::foo` class and want to make it right under the definition of class `A::B::foo` to make it easier to navigate and read code. Now I am getting an error `Cannot define or redeclare 'func' here because namespace 'B' does not enclose namespace 'A'`. Can I define my specialization somewhere near to `A::B::foo`?

I see the only way to close namespace `A::B`, define specialization and open namespace again to define `bar` and `foobar`, but it does not look very good to me:

```cpp
namespace A
{

template <typename T>
void func(T);

namespace B {

  class foo {};

}

template <>
void ::A::func(B::foo);

namespace B {

  class bar {};

  class foobar {};
  
}

}
```

Comment: I said that I want to make it easier to navigate code

Comment: Added that I want it to make easier to read code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t do this: there are no rules for how **name lookup** would work in a situation where you were inside namespace `B` lexically but inside `A` logically (via `func`).  (Note that you don’t need the `::A::` in the working version.)  There has been at least one [proposal](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0665r1.pdf) to allow this, and it might be revived at some point, but those rules would have to be written.